# ValueError: '12' is not a supported norm

Tags: python-3.x

In pycharm, getting error as:

```
in normalize raise ValueError("'%s' is not a supported norm" % norm)
ValueError: '12' is not a supported norm
```

Using `from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize` for computing TFIDF from scratch.

Can anybody suggest what needs to be done

Thank you,

Comment: Include the code that produces this error message.

Comment: Will you be able to provide the code snippet of the normalize() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are using [normalize()](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.normalize.html) function in sklearn. you have been using 12 as a norm value norm

```
normed_X = normalize(X, axis=0, norm='12')
```

as per the documentation the supported norms for parameter norm are 'l1', 'l2'' or 'max'

you have been using 12 instead of l2 replace the parameter value with l2 as below

```
normed_X = normalize(X, axis=0, norm='l2')
```

Comment: Thank you all, its working now. What Amila pointed out is correct.Below is my normalize() code sinppet                                                    
 normalize(csr_matrix((values, (rows,columns)),shape=(len(dataset),len(vocab))),norm='l2',axis=1,copy=True,return_norm=False)

Comment: Hi. Will you be able to make this answer accepted answer thank you.

Comment: can i know how can i make your answer accepted ? not seeing any options like that

Comment: Hi, Please use this link to get an idea. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work